# How does Lindlar's catalyst work?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, catalysis

I can not find a mechanism online. I understand that some poisoning effect causes the catalyst to be unable to reduce an alkene to alkane; however, if the catalyst is poisoned, how does it continue to reduce alkynes to alkenes?